# How do you assign the value of a type '[ViewController.answer]' to another view controller's type answer?

Tags: ios, swift

I am completing a project for school from the App Development with Swift textbook by Apple. I received an error for the pages 432-433 (image below).

[image: Pages 432-433 from the book]

My problem is this. When I attempt to pass the collection of answers from my Personality Quiz (the project is about building a personality quiz through XCode) from a view controller (which I titled, "QuestionViewController") to another view controller (titled, "ResultsViewController"), the following error occurs:

[image: My XCode error]

In order to pass the collection of answers, the book says I must use this code in the QuestionsViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:
    Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ResultsSegue" {
        let resultsViewController = segue.destination as!
          ResultsViewController
        resultsViewController.responses = answersChosen
    }
}
```

I have already added the code, "`var responses: [Answer]!`" to the ResultsViewController, which the book says allows this controller to receive the collection of answers from QuestionViewController. However, when I add the code to QuestionViewController from above, I get the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type '[QuestionViewController.Answer]' to type '[ResultsViewController.Answer]!'

I attempted to resolve this issue by placing the code, "`var responses: [Answer]!`" into the QuestionViewController as well, but that did not work. I also tried to add all of the code from my QuestionViewController to the ResultsViewController, but that did not work either.

If anyone has any idea as to what I can do to resolve this issue, please let me know. Also, if my request is unclear or you need additional information from my code to help solve the problem, I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: It looks like you've defined type `Answer` twice; once inside of each `ResultsViewController` and in `QuestionViewController`.  Instead, define `Answer` by itself outside of any other class or struct.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know if it worked @vacawama

Comment: I believe that worked. I defined Answer in a controller called QuestionDataController, and then I referenced Answer in the other controllers by simply adding the prefix "QuestionData." whenever I used the term Answer. This removed the error, and the app seems to be working just fine. Again, thank you! @vacawama

Comment: `Answer` should not be in any controller. It should be in its own file.